# Error while loading DyalogTutor_EN workspace in Dyalog APL, how to proceed?

Tags: apl, dyalog

I am unable to load the DyalogTutor_EN.dws file in Dyalog APL for Mac. The error is "There was an error ("TRANSLATION ERROR") with the specified file". How do I load this file in order to follow the book Mastering Dyalog APL which uses examples from this workspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug (which as been [logged](https://github.com/Dyalog/ride/issues/558)) appears if you use File>Open… as it inserts `)ED file://` before the filename.

For now, to work around the issue, edit the inserted line to read `)load`  (without `file://`):

[image: Session transcript]